# String format for storing timestamp value into database

Tags: database, timestamp

Which string format for storing timestamp value into database is most popular? In this case, we assume that we have no native database field type for timestamp (e.g. DateTime2 in Microsoft SQL Server)

I know there are

- ISO 8601
- Milliseconds from Epoch in UTC (e.g. [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html))

for it, but I guess there must be more suitable. ISO 8601 is better for human reading, but ISO 8601 is error prone unless every programmer absolutely store timestamp value after UTC+0 conversion. I guess ISO 8601 representation has no problem in sorting, but may have problem in some advanced indexing case.

Milliseconds from Epoch in UTC doesn't seem to be a standard or widely used format, but I am not sure.

Comment: Timestamps should be stored as timestamps, not as strings - because they are the former, not the latter.

Comment: Oops, I added more in my question: we cannot use DB native field type for timestamp.

Comment: Which database in the 21st century does not support a native "timestamp" data type.

Comment: For simplifying my question, I intentionally omitted this:
We send the timestamp value via REST API. We have to support several different database, and if we can, we want 'database agnostic' way.